# How to exclude certain attributes from being serialized

Tags: java, spring, gson

This question has been asked multiple time, I have a Java POJO class which I would like to serialize by excluding some attributes. In order to do this, I am using @Expose from GSON. The problem is that it does not seem to work.

Even if I use this:  Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation().create();

It does not work.

I am reluctant to use transient because it disables both serialization and deserialization of the given attribute.

Answer (score 0):

you can use transient

```
private transient String property;
```

Comment: I want to to able to deserialize it.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you initialize your Gson object properly. You should call excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation method in your GsonBuilder if you want to use the Exclude annotation.

For example
`Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation().create();`

[Gson javadoc description of excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.8.5/com/google/gson/GsonBuilder.html#excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation--)